# Calling Restart workbench code only once

Tags: java, eclipse, preference

I created a preference page with multiple fields. On preference store I added propertychangelistener when contains code to restart application.

```
getPreferenceStore().addPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener() {

      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
        if(MessageDialog.openConfirm(shell,"Restart Required", "Restart now?"))
          PlatformUI.getWorkbench().restart();
      }
    });
```

Problem is when I change multiple entries in preference page this restart code will be called that many times. What condition should I put so that even after changing multiple entries this restart will be called once only.

Comment: Can't you add a save/apply button and use that to prompt the user to restart the workbench?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set a flag in the property change listener and do the restart prompt in the `performOk` method of the page.

```
// Field in the page:
boolean restartRequired = false;


getPreferenceStore().addPropertyChangeListener(new IPropertyChangeListener() {

  @Override
  public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
    restartRequired = true;
  }
});


@Override
public boolean performOk()
{ 
  if (restartRequired) {
    ... prompt / restart
  }
  return super.performOk();
}
```

Comment: Thanks much greg-449 :)